# how to faster my code for compare two files in Python - for 1 GB size file (file.txt)

Tags: python, compare

how to faster my code for compare two files in Python - for 1 TB size file (file.txt)
my size file
f1.txt = 700MB  and other 100,000,000 lines
f2.txt = 370MB other 600K lines

```
f1 = open("./2/f1.txt", "r",encoding="utf8,") 
f2 = open("./2/f2.txt", "r",encoding="utf8") 
cc = open("./2/out.txt","w",encoding="utf8")
f1_raw = f1.readlines()
f2_raw = f2.readlines()
a = f1_raw 
b = f2_raw

for x in a:
    if not x in b:
        cc.write(x+"\n")
for x in b:
    if not x in a:
        cc.write(x)
f1.close()
f2.close()
cc.close()
```

Comment: Take a look at module ` difflib`.

Comment: idk it may help or not
but do read about pickling

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).
You have not yet researched algorithms for file difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a dictionary with every line in f1 as key and every line in f2 as value. Then do the loops on the dict.

```
f1 = open("file.txt")
f2 = open("dummy.txt")
f1_raw = f1.readlines()
f2_raw = f2.readlines()
a = f1_raw 
b = f2_raw

d = {}

for i,j in zip(a,b):
    d |= {i:j}

for c in a:
    if c in d.values():
        do something..

for k in b:
    if k in d.keys():
        do something..
```

Lists have Linear time complexity O(N) while dictionaries in python have constant time complexity O(1), means lookups are faster in dictionaries.